# How to connect two service producer networks in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am using two google managed services i.e Google Cloud SQL and Google Cloud Data Fusion. The cloud data fusion private IP instance is deployed inside a google managed VPC(Let's call it A) which is peered with my custom VPC(Lets Call it B).

Now my Cloud SQL Postgres is also installed in google managed VPC(Lets call it C).

A <-> B (peered)
B <-> C (peered)

Since A and C are google managed VPCs, I am not able to peer them. What should I do to make C accessible to A?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for [VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering) in GCP?

Comment: Yes. In the network peering console I don't see any option to peer two managed VPCs. Maybe it is done in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, consistent with your understanding that peered connections are not transitive, [Google recommends recommends setting up a proxy instance in your VPC so the two can communicate via the proxy](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/connect-to-cloud-sql-source).

Their instructions include:

1. Creating a VM instance running a TCP proxy in your VPC with an internal IP and public IP (internal IP only requires Private Google Access)
2. Create a firewall rule allowing traffic to your VM from the Cloud Data Fusion peered VPC IP range on whatever port you'd like (TCP).
3. Promote the VM's internal IP to a static IP.
4. Run a proxy on the VM so connections to whatever port you opened in the firewall is proxied to the database server listening port.
5. Connect Cloud Data Fusion to the proxy's static internal IP.

Consult the linked documentation for specific examples of creating this proxy with `gcloud` or other means.

Alternative methods (depending on whether your Cloud SQL instance or Cloud Data Fusion instance have a public or private IP) mentioned in the documentation are:

- A public Cloud Data Fusion instance to a public Cloud SQL instance (by using a public Cloud SQL proxy or allowlisting the 0.0.0.0/0 range in an authorized network). See the public IP connection option for Cloud SQL.
- A private Cloud Data Fusion instance and public Cloud SQL instance (by using a public Cloud SQL proxy in an authorized network).
- A public Cloud Data Fusion instance and a private Cloud SQL instance.